# Do not hide Point when zoom out, MapWinGis

Tags: c++, mfc, mapwingis

I'm using MapWinGis with C++/MFC.

I insert a lot of shapes into a ShapeFile(type is SHP_POINT).

When zoom out, distance between shapes become small and small. When small enough, some shapes cannot be displayed on the map, they become invisible.

At this time, if I select shapes by polygon, only the visible shapes can be selected, but I want to select all shapes inside the polygon.

So, is it possible to make MapWinGis not to hide shapes when zoom out?

Or, is it possible to select invisible shapes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to select all shapes inside a polygon, you have first to make sure you allow collision between point symbols on the map like the below sample code:

```
// sample code    
var sf = new Shapefile();
sf.CreateNew("", ShpfileType.SHP_POINT);
sf.CollisionMode = tkCollisionMode.AllowCollisions;
```

**As in [MapWinGis Documentation](https://www.mapwindow.org/mapwingis/_enumerations_8cs.html#a4b9c9db9e529a648a8f805cd11bbcf3a)**

> **[CollisionMode](https://www.mapwindow.org/mapwingis/_enumerations_8cs.html#a4b9c9db9e529a648a8f805cd11bbcf3a)** : [AllowCollisions, LocalList, GlobalList]
> **tkCollisionMode Shapefile.CollisionMode**
>
> (Gets or sets collision mode for point symbols for point, multi-point
> shapefiles and labels).